# Indenting a new line within a caption

Tags: captions

In the following MWE, I have a figure with a caption that has a main text ("lipsum") followed by a new line of annotation.

I'd like to indent the new line of annotation text by `\quad` or a similar width? How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{\lipsum[1][1-3]
\\\quad This is an annotation that I would like to indent by quad or similar spacing.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, space is removed at the beginning of a new line. Use `\hspace*{1em}`, because this makes unremovable space:

```
  \caption{\lipsum[1][1-3]\\
    \hspace*{1em}This is an annotation that I would like 
    to indent by quad or similar spacing.}
```

Note no space in front of `This'.

By the way, `\begin{table}[!h]` is a good method for blocking the table float queue. It's usually unlikely that floats find room exactly where we wish them to be. Actually, my opinion is that floats should always go top (maybe, rarely, bottom) of the page. Perhaps exceptions can be made for small floats. Having them in the middle of the text is distracting, particularly if they are in the middle of a paragraph.

The caption and a precise reference are more than sufficient for the reader to find the float referred to.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{\lipsum[1][1-3]
\\ \null\quad This is an annotation that I would like to indent by quad or similar spacing.}
\end{figure}
```

[image]